# CRM 2013 BPF using a composite field

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, composite, business-process

I'm trying to customize the OOB Case entity in CRM 2013. The "**Full Name**" composite field is required by default, and I would like to add it to my BPF. For whatever reason, this field will not show in the DDM, when I'm editing my BPF. I already confirmed I have the correct entity selected, but it refuses to show up.

Is there a special trick to getting OOB fields to display in the BPF DDM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composite fields are not supported in Business Process Flows. This is also noted in [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2013/10/22/using-the-business-process-flow-designer/).
You will instead have to add the underlying fields to the Business Process Flow.

In the case of the *Full Name* field on Contact (there is no Full Name field on Case), you can instead add the underlying *First Name* and *Last Name* fields to the Business Process Flow.